# Tracking file history in Azure App service

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm hosting a website on Azure using an App Service. Suddenly one of the .config files (I have both a Web.config and a Config.config file) went missing and the website stopped working.

When I deploy the website to Azure for some reason the Config.config file is not included (even though I set it to be copied always) and I have to add it manually afterwards. But there were no recent deploys for that website, so I have no explanation for how that file suddenly disappeared and caused the website to crash.

I was wondering if there is any way to pin down the exact moment when the file was deleted and what caused it to be deleted (if a certain user deleted it or something like that)? A Git-like history for the files hosted in the Azure App Service, if you will...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you enabled the `Web server logging` in your web app in the portal -> `App Service logs` like below.

[image]

If you enabled it, the log will send to your storage blob container which you configured. If not, I suppose you may could not find the log.

For example, I delete the file `test.js` in the kudu console `wwwroot` of my web app, you could find the log in the storage like below.

[image]

For more details about app service logs, you could check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs)(the doc has not been updated for three years, something is different from that currently).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Joy. Logging is enabled, but unfortunately the retention period was set to 1 day only. And I found out about the problem later than 24 hours. I guess there's nothing I can do in that case, right?